# Selectively correcting LFs to CRLFs

Tags: text-processing, newlines

Given:

- a large directory tree containing a mixture of:

  - files with LF line endings
  - files with CRLF line endings
  - files with a weird mix of both LF and CRLF line endings (due to a bug)
  - binary files
  - other files that I don't want to touch even if broken
- paths that might contain spaces

My goal was to leave the LF-only and CRLF-only files alone, and convert the hybrid files to CRLF-only files, while leaving the final two groups alone as well.

This incantation works:

```
find . (some conditions to exclude stuff I don't want to mess with) |
    xargs -d '\n' unix2dos -ic | cut -c 3- |
    xargs -d '\n' dos2unix -ic | cut -c 3- |
    xargs -d '\n' unix2dos
```

But now I'm curious whether there is a better / more efficient way to do it.  (Using only standard shell tools, not Perl/Python/etc.)

FWIW, the first `unix2dos -ic` is to filter the initial list to just those files containing CRLF, then `dos2unix -ic` subfilters to those also containing LF, and the final one actually does the conversion.  The `cut` calls are to trim off the two leading spaces that confuse `xargs`, and the `-d` is to resolve issues with spaces in the filenames, since the output isn't quoted.